# How to prevent the CoreBluetooth library from prompting to turn-on an iOS device's bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to detect whether an iOS device has Bluetooth enabled so that I can prevent the CoreBluetooth library from prompting the app user to enable it.  I am NOT looking to check the state of the CBCentralManager; I just want to prevent the blue popup box so that it doesn't annoy my users.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use CoreBluetooth in your app without the dialog. So if you want to prevent it all together, you can't.

If you just want to prevent if if they have Bluetooth off, then checking the state of CBCentralManager first is the right approach (ie check to see if it == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff).